# nothing happens when I click configure build task in VSCODE saying no build task found

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, configure

When I Ctrl+shift+B I get this. I click it and it goes no-where. I wait thinking my computer is thinking but nothing. Tried to create a folder .vscode and place a tasks.json in it. VScode acts like it doesn't even see it. I expect VScode to bring the menus up that I see in all the other posts when they click it. Mine just is not going anywhere when I click it. Thanks

since i am not allowed to answer for some picky reason. we shall see if this survives. To help the poor guy that spent too long looking. I created a new folder and put scripts in with no .vscode. then ctrl+shift+p searched for tasks.auto clicked on whatever auto it came up with. It built a new settings.json. I copied the tasks.json from the other folder over and was able to build. finally. found this work around here https://techoverflow.net/2020/01/24/how-to-fix-platform-io-no-tasks-to-run-found-configure-tasks/

[configureBuildTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfRnN.png)

Comment: read the VSC tasks doc page on how to setup a build task, Why is it `file:read()` and `io.open()` sometimes `:` and sometimes `.`?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-linux

I had the same issue, then followed the tutorial. Afterwards the issue was gone.

Comment: I appreciate this. Nearly gave up on it. This may have re-inspired my learning. Keep on serving, some of us need just that little nudge to get over the hump.